# Any reason why the onclick event listener not working?

Tags: java, android

In the code below, the event listner for button savebutton causes a force close error.

The cancel button works.

```
else if(menuItemName=="Make Tenant InActive"){


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // get tenant id
       // inflate the layout
        // put id in textbox
        // get date dialog to work!
        try{
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(GetTenantList.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.tenant_inactive);
        dialog.setTitle("Make Tenant InActive(Left)");  
        int pos = menuInfo.position;
                Tenants t=(Tenants)
                tenants.getItem(pos);
        Log.e("id", Integer.toOctalString(t.get_id()));
        Log.e("Name",t.getFirstName().toString());

        int tenantid=t.get_id();
        final TextView idtxt =(TextView)
                dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtID);
        idtxt.setText(Integer.toString(tenantid));
        Button savebutton = (Button)
                dialog.findViewById(R.id.upadte);
        savebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int myid= Integer.parseInt(idtxt.getText().toString());             
                EditText dateInActive= (EditText)   
                        findViewById(R.id.txtInactive_Date);
                java.util.Date inactive = null;
                try {
                    inactive = fm.parse(dateInActive.getText().toString());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String  InActiveDate=fm.format(inactive);
                if(InActiveDate.length()==0)
                {

                    CharSequence msg ="Date InActive not entered";          
                    int duration =Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, duration);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                    return;
                }
                if(db.IsvalidDate(InActiveDate )==false)
                {
                    CharSequence msg ="Date must be entered in format yyyy-mm-dd";          
                    int duration =Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, duration);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                    return;
                }
                try{
                db.SetTenantInActive(myid, InActiveDate );
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("Setting InActive Err", e.toString());
                }

            }
        });


        Button cancelbutton = (Button)
                dialog.findViewById(R.id.back);
        cancelbutton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        dialog.show();  
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Bad err", e.toString());
        }


    }
```

Here is the logcat print.

```
02-12 18:59:37.470: W/dalvikvm(2624): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-12 18:59:37.491: E/AndroidRuntime(2624): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 18:59:37.491: E/AndroidRuntime(2624): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 18:59:37.491: E/AndroidRuntime(2624):     at com.example.metermanager.GetTenantList$1.onClick(GetTenantList.java:162)
02-12 18:59:37.491: E/AndroidRuntime(2624):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-12 18:59:37.491: E/AndroidRuntime(2624):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-12 18:59:37.491: E/AndroidRuntime(2624):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-12 18:59:37.491: E/AndroidRuntime(2624):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-12 18:59:37.491: E/AndroidRuntime(2624):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-12 18:59:37.491: E/AndroidRuntime(2624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-12 18:59:37.491: E/AndroidRuntime(2624):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 18:59:37.491: E/AndroidRuntime(2624):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-12 18:59:37.491: E/AndroidRuntime(2624):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-12 18:59:37.491: E/AndroidRuntime(2624):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-12 18:59:37.491: E/AndroidRuntime(2624):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 18:59:41.510: I/Process(2624): Sending signal. PID: 2624 SIG: 9
```

Other parts of the code are working properly.
Even the try..catch statement does not catch the error!

Ronald
I have made some changes as below on the click event.
Here the edits

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int myid= Integer.parseInt(idtxt.getText().toString());             
                EditText dateInActive= (EditText)   
                        findViewById(R.id.txtInactive_Date);

                try {

                    Date inactive = fm.parse(dateInActive.getText().toString());
                    String  InActiveDate=fm.format(inactive);


                if(InActiveDate.length()==0)
                {

                    CharSequence msg ="Date InActive not entered";          
                    int duration =Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, duration);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                    return;
                }
                if(db.IsvalidDate(InActiveDate )==false)
                {
                    CharSequence msg ="Date must be entered in format yyyy-mm-dd";          
                    int duration =Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, msg, duration);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                    return;
                }                               

                db.SetTenantInActive(myid, InActiveDate );
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("Setting InActive Err", e.toString());
                }


            }
```

Comment: GetTenantList.java:162 what is there at this line ?

Comment: It is the class name where the error happens. and i dont have numbers in my code!

Comment: This what is there.String  InActiveDate=fm.format(inactive);

Comment: then `fm` is causing the problem, make sure `fm` is initialized before it reaches there.

Comment: inactive will be null root cause or fm is null.

Comment: Made some changes. Now i get a nullpointer Exception. see edits i have added to my question as edits.

Comment: fm is initialised. SimpleDateFormat fm =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: It seems i cant make it work...even a test with a  string throws the same error!  String  inactive  =  dateInActive.getText().toString();..yet similar thing work in another class!